# MYSQL select results from 3 tables with an array of ids

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I have 3 mysql tables where I need to extract data from. Anything to do with joins really gets me stuck!

Table 1 = products (productid, name)

Table 2 = category (categoryid, name)

Table 3 = categoryproduct (categoryid, productid) - my join table

I have an array of product ids which I need to get a random selection of products that fall into the same categories as these products.

The idea is that the results of the query will display a section in my cart of similar/related products that the customer may like

So something like

```
SELECT name etc FROM table1
WHERE table2.categoryid of results of the query = table3.categoryid of current products
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

How do I write that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP, following method will fetch 10 related products from database.

```
$productids = array(1002,789,999,203,321);

$sql = '
    SELECT * FROM 
    products p JOIN categoryproduct pc
        ON p.productid = pc.productid
    WHERE pc.categoryid IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT(categoryid) FROM 
        products inner_p JOIN categoryproduct inner_pc
            ON inner_p.productid = inner_pc.productid
        WHERE inner_p.productid IN('.implode(',',$productids).')
    )
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10';
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your problem correctly then this query may help. Here instead of subquery you can give comma separated string which contains categoryid of different products selected by the user.

```
    select p.name
    from products p,categoryproduct cp
    where p.productid=cp.productid
    and cp.categorid in(
    select categoryid 
    from cartitems)
    order by RAND()
```